# Restricting ssh access to server within a kerberos/ldap infrastructure

Tags: linux, ssh, kerberos, openldap

I have a MIT-Kerberos / OpenLDAP infrastructure. I want to limit the ssh-access for my users, so that only members of a specific group are allowed to ssh to my servers.
When I just had OpenLDAP without krb5, I used pam_access to restrict users:

```
 + : usersinternal : ALL
 - : ALL EXCEPT root : ALL
```

which did exactly what I wanted; and still does for PAM-Logins.

My Problem is that all users can login using SSO:

```
me@workstation ~ % ssh test@intern.example.com
test@intern.example.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
# user cannot login 

me@workstation ~ % kinit test
Password for test@EXAMPLE.COM: 
me@workstation ~ % ssh test@intern.example.com
test@intern:~$ ## login successful, i am on the server
Connection to intern.example.com closed.
```

here's the GSSAPI-Part of my sshd_config:

```
root@intern ~ # grep -i gssapi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
```

I think this is because when a users successfully authenticates against krb5 the PAM-Part is not used;
so what is a good way to limit who can log in; preferably via group or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `AllowGroups` option in the `sshd_config` file:

```
 AllowGroups
         This keyword can be followed by a list of group name patterns, separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for users whose primary group
         or supplementary group list matches one of the patterns.  Only group names are valid; a numerical group ID is not recognized.  By default, login is
         allowed for all groups.  The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

         See PATTERNS in ssh_config(5) for more information on patterns.
```